# Where does Fallout 4 store save files?

Tags: fallout-4

Where are the save games stored? I want to create a copy of them but I cannot find where they're stored!

Where do I need to look to find my save files?

Comment: If the goal is to create copies, can't you just... save in a new slot?

Comment: @Nelson I assume the goal is to backup a character or move one save file to another computer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On the PC version of the game, save games are stored in My Documents > My Games > Fallout4 > Saves. (`"%userprofile%\Documents\My Games\Fallout4\Saves"`)

Comment: Similar: on mine it's Documents > Saved Games > Fallout4 > Saves.

Answer (score 3):

My PC has the save location at:

```
$OSDRIVE:\Users\$USER\Documents\My Games\Fallout4\Saves
```

Where `$OSDRIVE` is the drive letter of my operating system (windows 7), and `$USER` is the name of the logged in user.

example: `C:\Users\user1234\Documents\My Games\Fallout4\Saves`